# Hydra yaml files being interpreted in an unexpected manner (string interpolation)

Tags: yaml, fb-hydra

Consider the following Hydra config file:

```
gap: "0_1"

target:
  params : "/bestpars_${gap}.json"
```

It seems that when I use this as a command line override as in

```
python foo.py gap="2_5"
```

the variable `target.params` is set to `/bestpars_25.json` What happened to the underscore? It does not appear to be a YAML special character, so I must be missing something.

Interestingly, two underscores go through unmolested (so, `2__5` is transmitted as intended) as does `a_b`, so there is some hidden numeric meaning to the underscore I am not aware of.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that if a yaml input only has numbers and underscores the underscores get stripped out, so you have to tell it is a string by quoting it. But I did quote it, you cry! Well, the shell strips out one level of quotes, so doing something like

```
python foo.py gap="'2_5'"
```

works. Disgusting, but effective.

Comment: Correct. YAML is being consistent with Python here. (try `x = 1_2`). Hydra's CLI parsing is also compatible with it. You are correct that the shell eats one level of quotes. A nicer way would be `'gap="2_5"'`.

Comment: See also the [tips on quoted values](https://hydra.cc/docs/1.1/advanced/override_grammar/basic/#quoted-values) from the Hydra docs.